# How to increase cell spaces in certain sections of PDF table and not the entire table using itext?

Tags: java, itext

I have created pdf pages using PDFTable and itext version 5.2.1
I have created a method which defines font, cell spacing,etc..
This is the code:

```
Cell textColspanCenter(String staticdata, Font font, int colspan, int rowspan, int border) {
        try {
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(staticdata, font));
            cell.setColspan(colspan);
            cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setBorder(border);
            cell.setPadding(4.0f);
            if (border == 1) {
                cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            }
            return cell;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("errorin textColspanLeft " + e);
            return null;
        }
```

I have set padding to 4..But my client wants some parts(cells, where user will write amounts and if they are too close to each other it will be difficult to match amounts to their source as it doesnot have any border) of my page to have more space between them than others(not the entire table)...
So I tried changing `cell.setPadding` values but it changes padding for entire table. All elements end up having more spaces...
I tried changing rowspan values but it messes up my entire table...
Any help is appreciated...Thanks

Comment: Guys I figured it out.... If anyone else has same problem, I created a new function similar to the one I mentioned but I added cell.setPaddingBottom(12.0f); in the above method and called it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the table. See this example:

```
float[] columnWidths = new float[] {10f, 20f, 30f, 10f};
table.setWidths(columnWidths);
```

If you want different cell widths from row to row, then you have to define a new table just bellow the current one. As far as I know, that is the only way.

If somebody knows other way, it would help me too. :)

Comment: Not the width..but more height will help